# How many bytes will the pointer skip?

Tags: c++

If I have the following code:

```
int * p = new int[2];
p[0] = 0;
p[1] = 1;
p++;
cout<<*p<<"\n";
```

Here, on incrementing `p`, it skips sizeof(int) bytes and goes to the `1` position. If `p` would have been of a different type, let's say `char`, then how many bytes would it have skipped? Will it be `1` or `4` only?

Comment: Why does it skip sizeof(int) bytes?

Comment: Are you not missing sizeof (int) in the malloc

Comment: if you're using C `int *p = malloc(2 * sizeof *p)`.  If you're using C++ `int *p = new int[2];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will skip `sizeof(decltype(*p))` bytes. In other words it will skip the size of the type `p` points to.

In this case `p` has the type `int*`, so it will skip `sizeof(int)` bytes. However, if `p` had the type `char*` it would skip `sizeof(char)` bytes.

Comment: Therefore, in that case, if it would have been of type `char`, it wouldn't have pointed to the next location, right? Since the array is of type int and each position in array will be of 4 bytes.

Comment: Yes. It would have only advanced `p` by 1 byte, which is the size of `char`. So it would be 3 bytes short of the next position if the size of `int` is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
int * p = (int*)malloc(2);
```

in general case is incorrect. A correct statement will look like

```
int * p = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof( int ) );
```

As you correctly pointed out yourself

> Here, on incrementing p, it skips sizeof(int) bytes and goes to the 1
>   position

On the other hand `sizeof( char )` in C++ and in C is always equal to `1`. So according to your own statement

> Here, on incrementing p, it skips **sizeof(char)** bytes and goes to the 1
>   position